# Is asking about Sci-Fi games on-topic?

Tags: support, scope, help-center

According to the [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

---

#### What topics can I ask about here?

Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:

- Plot, character, or setting explanations
- Historical or societal context of a work
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
- Story identification
- Franchise/series reading or viewing order

---

Now I'm curious if Sci-Fi games fall under any of these categories. So, are questions regarding Sci-Fi games allowed on this community?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  They totally 100% are.

Comment: You can ask about plot elements, not game mechanics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we have [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) and [games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) tags. The wiki for the former describes when it is appropriate to ask a question about a sci-fi (or fantasy) video game:

> For questions about the plot or backstory of a game with science-fiction/fantasy elements. Questions about playing the game or the mechanics are off-topic here, but may be on topic at Arqade (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). Game identification questions are also on topic as long as they're specifically about a Science Fiction and Fantasy game.

Similar guidelines apply to non-video games.